# How to display the contents of a tf.Variable

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and I appreciate knowing how to visualize the contents of a tf.Variable, tried% f,% s but it is not shown, where is my mistake.
I put the code that I am using, I appreciate your response.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
startIter = 2000
globalStep = tf.Variable(startIter, trainable=False)
x = tf.Variable(5.0, name="counter") 
for i in range(startIter): 
    totalLoss = x**2-20.0*x+1.0 
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001) 
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(totalLoss)
    grads = [(None, var) if grad is None else (tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1.0, 1.0), var) for grad, var in grads]
    applyGradientOp = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=globalStep)
    #print("opt.get_name(): ",opt.get_name(),"opt._lr: ",opt._lr,"opt._lr_t: %f "% (sess.run(opt._lr_t)))  #jll1
    print("opt.get_slot_names: ",opt.get_slot_names())
    print('  ', opt.get_slot(var,'m'))  # here
    print('  ', opt.get_slot(var,'v'))  # here
    assign_op = tf.assign(x, x + 1)
```

This result is displayed

```
('opt.get_slot_names: ', ['m', 'v'])
('  ', <tf.Variable 'counter/Adam_614:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>)
('  ', <tf.Variable 'counter/Adam_615:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>)
```

but I would like to visualize a value, of course if it is possible.

I understand that they are AdamOptimizer slots, and I seek to show the learning rate in each step. I have reviewed other answers but they do not work.
Use:

```
print ("opt.get_name ():", opt.get_name (), "opt._lr:", opt._lr, "opt._lr_t:", opt._lr_t) # jll1
```

before the print and the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.Print()` but this requires you to add it to your computational graph:

```
print_node = tf.Print(opt.get_slot(var,'m'), [opt.get_slot(var,'m')], 'm')
sess.run([print_node], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works, I have rearranged the code.

Answer (score 0):

To view the values in a tf.Variable, you need to run it with a TensorFlow session.  This should work:

```
print('  ', sess.run(opt.get_slot(var,'m')))  # here
print('  ', sess.run(opt.get_slot(var,'v')))  # here
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works, I have rearranged the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help, I reordered the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()   #jll2
startIter = 2000
globalStep = tf.Variable(startIter, trainable=False)
x = tf.Variable(5.0, name="counter")
for i in range(startIter): 
    totalLoss = x**2-20.0*x+1.0  
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)  
#    print("opt.get_name(): ",opt.get_name(),"opt._lr: ",opt._lr,"opt._lr_t: ",opt._lr_t)  #jll1
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(totalLoss)
    grads = [(None, var) if grad is None else (tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1.0, 1.0), var) for grad, var in grads]
    applyGradientOp = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=globalStep)
#    print('Learning rate opt._lr_t: %f' % (sess.run(opt._lr_t)))    #jll3             
#    print("opt.get_name(): ",opt.get_name(),"opt._lr: ",opt._lr,"opt._lr_t: %f "% (sess.run(opt._lr_t)))  #jll1
    print("opt.get_slot_names: ",opt.get_slot_names())
    #### **by matwilso**
    with sess.as_default():
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print('m:',sess.run(opt.get_slot(var,'m')),'v:',sess.run(opt.get_slot(var,'v')))
    #### **by Andreas Pasternak**
    with sess.as_default():
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print_node1 = tf.Print(opt.get_slot(var,'m'), [opt.get_slot(var,'m')], 'm')
        print_node2 = tf.Print(opt.get_slot(var,'v'), [opt.get_slot(var,'v')], 'v')
        print("['m', 'v']:",sess.run([print_node1,print_node2]))
    assign_op = tf.assign(x, x + 1)
# thanks
```

And now I get:

```
('opt.get_slot_names: ', ['m', 'v'])
('m:', 0.0, 'v:', 0.0)
("['m', 'v']:", [0.0, 0.0])
```

Comment: Note that you do not need to call `print` on the session object. `tf.Print()` already prints to the screen.

Comment: I agree thank you.
Is there a way to show the adaptive values of learning rate?